# Refresh and display updated time on tkinter box

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, tkinter

I am working on a project which is a tkinter box which shows the machine hostname along with current date and time. I have added a button on the box and when we click the button, it should refresh and show updated hostname and datetime on the window. below is my code.

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
import socket

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Check-In!")
root.geometry("270x175")
root.config(bg="gray27", highlightbackground="goldenrod2", highlightthickness=2)
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . top')

# creating values for entry
now = datetime.datetime.now()
machine = socket.gethostname()

def update_info():
    root.update()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Refresh", "Info Refreshed")

lbl1 = Label(root, text=machine, font=("Bell MT", 16, "bold"), bg="gray20",fg="sky blue")
lbl1.place(x=35, y=30)
lbl2 = Label(root, text=now, font=("Bell MT", 14, "bold"), bg="gray20",fg="green")
lbl2.place(x=15, y=70)
Btn1 = Button(root, text="Refresh info", command=update_info, bd=3, font=("Bell MT", 12, "bold"), bg="gray20", fg="sky blue", width=11)
Btn1.place(x=141, y=131)

root.mainloop()
```

when i run the code it displays the current date time and the machine hostname, but when i click on refresh info button after some time, it does not show the updated date time. some how `root.update()` is not working here.

Can some one please help .

Answer (score 0):

mainloop() is basically and end to your code. The better method is to change it with update() and update_idletasks() allowing you to add to the mainloop.

Edit: re-reading question. Your function never alters the value of lbl2 so why would it ever update? 'now' is set long before and never updated so it will always update to the same value even if you tried updating it.

```
while True:
  lbl2.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now())
  root.update() # these 2 have the same function as mainloop but can be added to.
  root.update_idletasks()
```

Bonus points: add your own quitting flag:

```
quitter = False
root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quitting)
#code here

def quitting():
  global quitter #Tkinter works better as a class so this is a workaround
  quitter = Ture
  # add any code needed to exit the application here

while not quitter:
  root.update()
  root.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: Thanks..  now the clock keeps running on the window..which i want only to show the updated time only when clicked on the button.

Comment: add lbl2.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now()) to the update_info() function replacing everything that is there already.

Comment: Directly calling  `update` is definitely not the better solution. As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't ever call `update`, and rarely is it truly needed. Your `while` loop with `update` is considerably more inefficient than using `mainloop`.

Answer (score 0):

The label won't automatically update, you must configure it to display new text.

```
def update_info():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    lb2.configure(text=now)
```

If you want it to automatically refresh, you can use `after` which places itself on a queue to be run when the time expires. For example:

```
def update_info():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    lb2.configure(text=now)
    root.after(1000, update_info)
```

With that, when you call it once it will automatically schedule itself to be called again in one second.